# adb pull freezes when it encounters kmsg

Tags: android, adb, boot

I'm trying to debug why my android mobile will not boot. When I run:

```
adb pull / e:\temp
```

It freezes at

```
pull: /proc/kmsg -> e:\temp/proc/kmsg
```

Is there some way to stop it freezing here or to get 'pull' to by-pass this file.

(I'm running this command while the phone is sitting in the recovery menu as I cant get adb to run in any other state).

Samsung Galaxy GT-i5500, android 2.2, windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead dump the log using

```
adb logcat -d > log.txt
```

This will provide you with the log which you can use to debug the issue.

Run-time messages can be obtained through

```
adb shell dmesg
```

For `kmsg`, the following command can be tried.

```
adb shell cat /proc/kmesg
```